# Powershell- remotely executing the script on servers

Tags: powershell, cross-domain

I am trying to run below powershell script from server01. I have account on server03, so didn't pass the credentials. Even if I pass it, the same error message comes up.

My account is on domainA and server01 and server 03 is on domainB. If I logged into server01 with another account which belongs to DomainB, then the script works.

Is there anything else I need to enable before I do cross domain PS execution?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server03 -FilePath E:test\test.ps1

[Server03] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: The network path was not found.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or us
e HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information,
 see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: This is the double hop problem.  Consider using CredSSP, but research it thoroughly as there may be security implications for enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added FDQN for the server and it worked fine.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server03.domain.com -FilePath E:test\test.ps1

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add the computer in trusted hosts list.
- check for the servers that are part of your trusted host lists.

  `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts`

  `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value “IPAddress or *”`

then proceed with your commands.